# DJANGO: TYPE ERROR: an integer is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Please help!
I am new to DJANGO and have little experience coding.  I am working through a tutorial that involves building a shopping cart.  When the user navigates to localhost/cart/cart the code should create a cart.

I had a previous error which I fixed but the fix appears to have unmasked a different problem.  ALthough the cart loads, no cart is created in admin portal.  When attempting to create the cart from the DJANGO admin UI manually on clicking add the following error appears:

**Traceback error**

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/cart/cart/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1653, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1534, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1580, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1093, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1339, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1281, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1512, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 523, in adapt_decimalfield_value
    return utils.format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)
  File "C:\Users\nia\Desktop\Pharma-mart\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 233, in format_number
    context.prec = max_digits
TypeError: an integer is required
```

**cart/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from store.models import product, customer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", default= None)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id =cart_id)
        if qs.count()==1:
            new_obj = False
            cart_obj = qs.first()
            if request.user.is_authenticated() and cart_obj.user is None:
                cart_obj-save()
            else:
                cart_obj = cart.objects.new(user=request.user)
                new_obj = True
                request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
            return cart_obj, new_obj

    def new(self, user = None):
        user_obj = None
        if user is not None:
            if user is authenticated():
                user_obj = user
        return self.model.objects.create(user=user_obj)

class cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ManyToManyField('store.product')
    total = models.DecimalField(default = 0.0, max_digits = 50.00, decimal_places = 2)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = CartManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**cart/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import cart

# Create your views here.
#def cart_create(user=None):
#   cart_obj = cart.objects.create(user = None)
#   print('New Cart created')
#   return cart_obj

def cart_home(request):
    cart_obj = cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    print('cart_obj:', cart_obj)
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
'''
__cart/admin.py__

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import cart

admin.site.register(cart)
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = ''

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'store',
    'patients',
    'ckeditor',
    'cart',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pharmamart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / ''],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pharmamart.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ""
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = ""
```

Comment: Here `models.DecimalField(default = 0.0, max_digits = 50.00, decimal_places = 2)` Why is `max_digits` set to a float? I believe this is the cause of your error, It is meant to be an **integer** so you should write `max_digits = 50`. (In fact why 50 digits? that's a very big number there likely wouldn't be anything having that high a price in your shop)

Comment: Thankyou Abdul.  That has happily resolved the issue

Comment: In reply to your question I am not sure why the tutorial includes the field in that manner as I agree it appears incorrect and unnecessarily high